# Pymacs lisp version rarities

Tags: python, emacs23, ropemacs, pymacs

I am running Ubuntu Natty and install Emacs and pymacs and ropemacs all from the repos. So when I add to my .emacs file the script to load ropemacs and pymacs I get the following error:

File mode specification error: (error "Pymacs Lisp version is 0.23, Python is 0.24-beta2"

I've been reading the docs and readmes but I haven't found out what is happening here. So I turn to you. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I had to do to fix this was install this package https://launchpad.net/~portis25/+archive/emacs/+build/2287757
Ubuntu automatically upgrades it and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message indicates that the Elisp and Python sides of Pymacs aren't in synch.

Perhaps this is some sort of packaging problem. The Pymacs version in Ubuntu Natty is 0.23, according to http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/pymacs.

I use Pymacs 0.24-beta2 downloaded from https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs/downloads.

The Elisp part of Pymacs is in **pymacs.el**. In my copy of that file it says:

```
Pymacs Lisp version is 0.24-beta2...
```

In **pymacs.py**, it says:

```
lisp._protocol.send('version', '"0.24-beta2"')
```

Comment: Let me check that out and see if that is the problem. Perhaps the repo versions are quite old or something like that.

Comment: Did you also install it via the repos?

Answer (score 0):

I install pymacs manually the python part,and i use the pymacs package in the elpa's python-mode (it contains pymacs.el),then this two conflict,i remove the pymacs in python-mode,it works well.maybe you are the same error.Or you should check your python version.